# Mongoose : save embedded docs after the push method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, save, mongoose

i scruted the API doc of mongoose but i haven't found a clue for my problem.
I want use the push function for add a new child to a tab children.
Child has the same structure of his parent.

this not working with that :

```
function get_directory(id, cb) {
    // if argument id is omited, we return directly the mainDir

    model.findOne(...select the main object, function(mainDir) {
        recurse_in_the_main_object(mainDir, id)
        callback ( dir_founded )
    });
};

function add_directory(parentDir_id, specs, cb) {
    get_directory(parentDir_id, function(dir) {
        dir.push({..........});

        get_directory(function(mainDir) {
           mainDir.save();
        });
    });
});
```

but working with that :

```
function get_directory(id, cb) {
    // if argument id is omited, we return directly the mainDir

    model.findOne(...select the main object, function(mainDir) {
        recurse_in_the_main_object(mainDir, id)
        callback ( dir_founded, mainDir)
    });
};

function add_directory(parentDir_id, specs, cb) {
    get_directory(parentDir_id, function(dir, mainDir) {
        dir.push({..........});              
        mainDir.save();
    });          
});
```

It's maybe a async problem (the new dir is well pushed but no save) but even with cb or setTimeout, that's persist !
I just would known why the ex1 doesn't work...sorry for my english ^^'

Thanks !!!